# How do you make a discord bot resend a image you just send discord.js

Tags: javascript, image, discord, discord.js

Im making a bot that has a feature called "Discord Funniest Memes" or DFM for short. The point of the feature is people can submit memes in #memes using the command "DFM.submit 'IMAGEFILE'" and then if people do the command "DFM" it will send some of the highest voted memes of the day/week, but the problem I am having is the bot isn't sending the image and is instead giving me a error message.

Edit: I forgot the error message "(node:3532) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Cannot send an empty message"

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const bot = new Discord.Client();
var meme
const DFM = ['some meme link.png', 'another meme link.png']
var randomDFM = DFM[Math.floor(Math.random() * DFM.length)];
            if(message.content.startsWith("DFM.submit")){
                let meme = message.content.split(" ");
                meme.shift();
                meme = meme.join(" ");
                message.channel.send(meme)
                message.channel.send('Your post was submitted to "Discords Funniest Memes"')
                DFM.unshift(meme)
            }
            if(message.content === "DFM"){
                message.channel.send(randomDFM)
                randomDFM = DFM[Math.floor(Math.random() * DFM.length)];
        }
bot.login('no token for you')
```

Comment: What is the error message you get? Please always include it.

Comment: I completely forgot anyways I added it. Thanks for asking

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `meme` is empty at the time of calling `send()`,

`UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning` happens when you don't properly catch an error that's thrown (rejected) by a promise. Unless you `await` or call `.then()` on the promise, the remaining code will continue through without waiting for the result of the `send()` method. If there's an error while `send()` is running in the background without being waited for, that's when you get `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning`.

From the looks of `discord.js`'s docs, `message.channel.send` returns a promise. Have a look [at the docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=send) and how they use `then()` and `catch()`.

What you likely want to be doing is something like so. This is untested, but should give you an idea.

```js
message.channel.send(meme)
    .then(() => {
        return message.channel.send('Your post was submitted to ...');
    })
    .catch(error => {
        // handle your error here
        console.error(error);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to send an image to the channel you need to reformat your `message.channel.send` command.

It should look like this:

```
if(message.content === "DFM"){
    // randomDFM should contain the url to the file you are trying to send
    message.channel.send("Your Bot's Message", {files: [randomDFM]})
    randomDFM = DFM[Math.floor(Math.random() * DFM.length)]
}
```

`message.channel.send` also returns a promise, so you will need to ensure you are handling errors as well.

That you would look like this:

```
if(message.content === "DFM"){
    // randomDFM should contain the url to the file you are trying to send
    message.channel.send("Your Bot's Message", {files: [randomDFM]})
    .then(() => {
        randomDFM = DFM[Math.floor(Math.random() * DFM.length)]
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
    }
}
```